# Calling async javascript code in a Silverlight project

Tags: javascript, silverlight

We are using Silverlight as our solution for a web interface. We have an existing web-service, but placing a crossdomain and clientaccesspolicy file into the root of the server is our last resort, so we're exploring other options first. I've decided another way to go is use HtmlPage.Window.Invoke() and use javascript to call the webservice, receive the JSON data, and return it to the Silverlight enviornment where I'll parse it accordingly. I've run into 2 problems:

If I call it synchronously my UI thread freezes until the call is complete and I have no idea how to work around it. I'm under the impression that the UI thread is the only one that can access javascript.

If I call it asynchronously I don't know how to NOT return data until readyState==4. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there some kind of XML Data Island alternative for JSON that will work with IE7+, Chrome, Firefox 3+, and the newer versions of Safari?

Comment: If you have additional questions or detail to add to your question just edit your question rather than commenting on it.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by `how to NOT return data`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the fundemental `XmlHttpRequest` solution that ought to work on most of the latest browsers:-

Javascript:-

```
 function getSomeJSON(url, callback)
 {
     var result = null;
     var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("GET", url, true);
     xhr.onreadystatechanged = function()
     {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4)
          {
              if (xhr.status == 200)
              {
                  result = xhr.responseText;
              }
              xhr = null;
              callback(result);
          }
     }
     xhr.send(null);
 }
```

In Sliverlight C#

```
 void FetchData()
 {
     string url = GenerateUrlForService();
     HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("getSomeJSON", new Action<string>(jsonResult =>
     {
         // Code here to handle the json string result.
         // This will run asynchronously so should not block the UI thread 
         // for the duration of the web service call.
     }));

 }
```

Comment: You could alternately use jQuery's ajax API in place of the XmlHttpRequest if you didn't want to manually handle the request. Either way, I agree that using some callback method is the best approach when dealing with asynchronous requests.